# Regresar a mi seleccion por default con AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5

Tengo un select que contiene varias opciones que estan ocultas pero se van mostrando segun la que se vaya escogiendo, por ejemplo, al seleccionar la opcion Nivel 1 se muestra la opcion Nivel 2 y al seleccionar la opcion Nivel 3 se muestra las opciones Nivel 1 Nivel 2 y Nivel 3, lo que pasa es que al seleccionar una quiero que se regrese el select a la opcion por defecto de "Seleccione Nivel". Lo he intentado con ng-change="nivelSeleccion =' ' "; y si me regresa la seleccion por defecto pero solo me muestra la opcion nivel 1 es como si volviera a empezar y yo quiero que cada vez que seleccione un nivel me muestre los que siguen pero que tenga la opcion por defecto ya seleccionada. 
este es el codigo html:

```
<select class="minimal" ng-model="nivelSeleccion" ng-change="addRow()" ng-init="nivelSeleccion=''">
<option value="">Seleccione nivel</option>
<option value="nivel1">Nivel 1</option>
<option value="nivel2" ng-show="nivelSeleccion=='nivel1' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel3' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel2' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel4' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel5' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel6' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel7' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel8' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel9' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel10'">Nivel 2</option>
<option value="nivel3" ng-show="nivelSeleccion=='nivel2' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel4' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel3' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel5' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel6' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel7' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel8' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel9' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel10'">Nivel 3</option>
<option value="nivel4" ng-show="nivelSeleccion=='nivel3' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel4' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel5' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel6' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel7' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel8' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel9' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel10'">Nivel 4</option>
<option value="nivel5" ng-show="nivelSeleccion=='nivel4' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel5' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel6' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel7' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel8' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel9' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel10'">Nivel 5</option>
<option value="nivel6" ng-show="nivelSeleccion=='nivel5' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel6' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel7' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel8' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel9' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel10'">Nivel 6</option>
<option value="nivel7" ng-show="nivelSeleccion=='nivel6' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel7' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel8' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel9' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel10'">Nivel 7</option>
<option value="nivel8" ng-show="nivelSeleccion=='nivel7' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel8' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel9' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel10'">Nivel 8</option>
<option value="nivel9" ng-show="nivelSeleccion=='nivel8' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel9' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel10'">Nivel 9</option>
<option value="nivel10" ng-show="nivelSeleccion=='nivel9' || nivelSeleccion=='nivel10'">Nivel 10</option>
</select>
```

---

Comment: nivelSeleccion = null, con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y muestra el código del controller